# Expo package with native code (objective-c and java)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

It's common to run into situations where we need a third party library that uses native code. Examples: PayPal integration, access to the wireless system, etc.

The official answer for this is "**you have to eject**". Alright, everybody knows that I know that - no need to reply with this, please.

But there are expo packages that use native code. For example, the [react-native-appearance](https://github.com/expo/react-native-appearance).

So it is possible to create expo libraries that use native ios/android code. But I wonder how? I found no documentation about it. It seems to me that only the Expo core team knows about it because I only see this being used on packages developed by the Expo core team. Maybe I am not looking it right, but I found none, zero information on how packages like `react-native-appearance` are made.

**Question:**
How to create an expo package that contains native ios/android code (like `react-native-appearance`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expo packages a whole bunch of Native Modules with the SDK, including react-native-appearance.  If the Native code is included in the SDK, then you can use it, otherwise you might have to eject.  Case-in-point, a hello-word expo app is much larger in size that a bare React-native-init hello-world app.